# Is there a way to create multiple (nearly identical) objects at the same time?

Tags: c#, winforms, object, optimization, formatting

I apologize for the poorly worded title, but I really am not quite sure how else to put it. I asked a similar question roughly an hour ago regarding functions, but this has to do with the initialization of objects, specifically when using WinForms. Relevant code:

```
        // 
        // textBoxCTotal
        // 
        this.textBoxCTotal.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
        resources.ApplyResources(this.textBoxCTotal, "textBoxCTotal");
        this.textBoxCTotal.Name = "textBoxCTotal";
        this.textBoxCTotal.TabStop = false;

        // 
        // textBoxBTotal
        // 
        this.textBoxBTotal.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
        resources.ApplyResources(this.textBoxBTotal, "textBoxBTotal");
        this.textBoxBTotal.Name = "textBoxBTotal";
        this.textBoxBTotal.TabStop = false;

        // 
        // textBoxRTotal
        // 
        this.textBoxRTotal.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
        resources.ApplyResources(this.textBoxRTotal, "textBoxRTotal");
        this.textBoxRTotal.Name = "textBoxRTotal";
        this.textBoxRTotal.TabStop = false;
```

Is it possible to initialize these 3 objects (if that's the correct name) at once, slimming the code down by nearly 66%? I feel as though there must be a more compact way.

I am happy to clarify any wording, as I am sure I may not have been as clear as possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this code from auto-generated designer class?

Comment: As SeM suspects: If this is designer-code: Don't touch it! If you write this by yourself: you can make a function that takes a TextBox Argument and perform the settings as shown. Then just pass the respective textboxes to that function. It won't be "at once" - but you'll reduce code duplication significantly.

Comment: I imagine the reason I would want to leave it alone is that: if I go to make changes within the Designer, it will regenerate the entire code structure that was there before? Or simply break the Designer?

Comment: Exactly. You never know what you will break if you change the auto-generated code from the designer. So for the sake of better tooling: Leave it alone. But in a different context, where there is no designer involved, you can (and should) of course optimize it.

Comment: Don't touch the designer-generated code under any circumstances, particularly the method commented with `do not modify the contents of this method with the code editor`. You will regret it if you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is: This is called "refactoring":

```
 private void InitializeTextBox(TextBox textBox, string name) {
      textBox.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
      resources.ApplyResources(textBox, name);
      textBox.Name = name;
      textBox.TabStop = false;
 }
```

And you can use it like this:

```
 InitializeTextBox(this.textBoxBTotal, nameof(this.textBoxBTotal));
```

However be aware that this is autogenerated code using the windows forms designer. If you edit that code, it will not always be possible to make more changes afterwards *via the editor*. So maybe living with that duplication is OK in that case.

Comment: side note - you can use the `nameof` inside the method, so you don't have to pass the name of the textbox as well.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - no you can't - that will become "textBox" which is not what the OP wants. `nameof (textBox)` will be "textBox".

Comment: Totally agree - except the method name - maybe InitialiseTextBox would be clearer in this example.